Get DHCP Gateway networkd-dispatcher
For Ubuntu 24.04 Server, is there a way to get the DHCP gateway in a networkd-dispatcher script when the DHCP interface comes up/is renewed (like $new_router in a dhclient hook script).
Update after original post:
I did find the gateway in the $json environment variable that is passed in networkd-dispatcher .. but ... (1) may change/is not standardized according to dev page and (2) I need to let netplan set the default route.  I was hopeful that I could get the gateway and update a custom table without impacting the default route - is that possible?

Apart what I said in the question (use the $json environment variable), I have not been able to get the DHCP gateway using networkd-dispatcher and systemd-networkd.
The way I went to get the data I needed was to stop using systemd-networkd and download NetworkManager - the dispatcher there will give you the DHCP Routers in the environment variable DHCP4_ROUTERS.  The DHCP4_ROUTERS is available in the script even if you do not use the NetworkManager DHCP client to set the default routers.

#!/bin/bash
interface="eth0"
IP=$(ifconfig $interface  | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')
Broadcast=$(ifconfig $interface  | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f3 | awk '{ print $1}')
Port="5001"

while [ true ];
do
    sleep 1
    echo $IP | socat - UDP4-DATAGRAM:$Broadcast:$Port,so-broadcast
    #to listen: netcat -l -u $Broadcast -p $Port
done
exit 0

